# Partial derivative of three functions/Jacobian

Tags: partial-derivative, cubics, jacobian

If $u$, $v$ and $w$ are the roots of the cubic $(\lambda - x)^3 + (\lambda - y)^3 + (\lambda - z)^3 = 0$ in $\lambda$, then find partial derivative of $u$, $v$ and $w$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$.

More importantly, I'd like to know how could I express $u$, $v$ and $w$ in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$?

Comment: So, can you expand the inital cubic and rearrange so that it is cubic in $\lambda$? Can you then solve for $u, v, w$?

Comment: @Kevin I did try that, but I couldn't find the roots (u, v and w)

Comment: I can add some thoughts

Comment: I expect that the point of this exercise is to come up with a way to do this _without_ explicitly finding expressions for $u$, $v$ and $w$ in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$. Looks like you’ll need to use some combination of the chain rule and the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @amd could you give a solution to this? I haven't been taught "inverse function theorem", let alone I don't understand how to proceed with your method

Comment: Then that’s not the way to approach this problem. Are you allowed to leave the solution in terms of $u$, $v$ and $w$? If not, it’s going to be very ugly indeed. If so, then Vieta’s formulas are the way to go, as in [Kevin’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2921615/265466). You’ll end up with a system of linear equations in the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts (ie, a possible hint)

Expanding the above, I found (please check)
$$3 \lambda^3 - (x+y+z)\lambda^2-[(x^2-2x)+(y^2-2y)+(z^2-2z)] \lambda + 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x^3+y^3+z^3)=0$$

Write
\begin{align}
p(x, y, z) &= (x+y+z)\\
q(x,y , z) &= -(x^2-2x)-(y^2-2y)-(z^2-2z) \\
r(x, y, z) &= 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x^3+y^3+z^3)
\end{align}
Now, by [Vieta's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) formula (and using your notation for roots)
\begin{align}
u+v+w &= (x+y+z)\\
uv+vw+wu &= -(x^2-2x)-(y^2-2y)-(z^2-2z) \\
uvw &= 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x^3+y^3+z^3)
\end{align}
Now it is tedious and fellow posters may point you toward a more elegant way of finding $u, v, w$ but this way is a useful exercise in algebra!

Comment: Good idea, but your expansion of the polynomial doesn’t look right. The sum of the exponents in every term should be $3$.